# how does go-pg covers linked tables

Tags: go, go-pg

Having three tables with the following specifications:

```
type Devices struct {
   ID         int
   Name  string
}
```

and

```
type Features struct {
   ID        int
   Name string
}
```

I have created a linked table specified by the following struct:

```
type DevicesFeatures struct {
    DeviceID   int
    Device *Devices
    FeatureID int
    Feature *Features
}
```

I want to select all the devices and their features if any.
A query like the below one works for me:

```
select A.name, C.name from devices as A left join devices_fearures as B on A.id =B.device_id left join features as C on C.id = B.feature_id
```